# PostgreSQL: get count of occurrences of specified element in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to calculate the count of occurrences of specified element in array, something like:

> `elem_occurrences_count(ARRAY[a,b,c,a,a], a) = 3`
>
> `elem_occurrences_count(ARRAY[a,b,c], d) = 0`

Is there any function in PostgreSQL that can be used to solve the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked [Array functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) in the official docs?

Comment: See my answer for how to do this with [modern versions 9.5+ of PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42711911/124486)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to unnest the array and then count the occurrences.

```
with elements (element) as (
   select unnest(ARRAY['a','b','c','a','a'])
)
select count(*)
from elements
where element = 'a';
```

This can easily be embedded into a function:

```
create or replace function count_elements(elements text[], to_find text)
  returns bigint
as
$body$
  select count(*) 
  from unnest(elements) element 
  where element =  to_find;
$body$
language sql;
```

**Update**

Since Postgres 9.5 this can also be done using `array_positions()` which returns an array of positions where an element was found. The length of that array is the number of occurrences:

```
select cardinality(array_positions(ARRAY['a','b','c','a','a'], 'a'));
```

Comment: This solution is worked for me, but performance is hardly degrading compared with such snippet:    `(array_length(string_to_array(combined_elements_as_one_text, CAST(element AS varchar)), 1) - 1)`. Do you have any ideas how to increase performance?

Comment: @StanislavBelyakov: sorry, I don't understand that snipped. What is `combined_elements_as_one_text`? And I don't see how you could get the number of occurrences of a specific value using `array_length`

Comment: `combined_elements_as_one_text` is a list of elements (`elements text[]`) that were casted to varchar and joined as one text string. There is a `string_to_array` function that splits the string (`combined_elements_as_one_text`) with the specified delimiter `CAST(element AS varchar))` into array. This array always contain counts of element that equal to occurrence count plus one.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Cool trick. It would fail if "element" can be a `,` or `{` or `}`. If that is faster, then you should use that (or re-think your data model: parsing arrays and comma delimited strings is almost always a sign of bad design)

Comment: forgot to say that elements are UUIDs, so described failure cases doesn't affect me. Unfortunately, I cannot change my data model, therefore I have to use such trick.

Answer (score 3):

## 9.5+

There is an easier method now

```
SELECT
  sArray,
  c,
  coalesce(array_length( array_positions(sArray, c), 1 ),0) AS count
FROM ( VALUES
  (ARRAY['a','b','c','a','a'], 'a'),
  (ARRAY['a','b','c'], 'd')
) AS t(sArray,c);

   sarray    | c | count 
-------------+---+-------
 {a,b,c,a,a} | a |     3
 {a,b,c}     | d |     0
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

The occurrence of all elements in an array can be found with this query:

```
SELECT count(id), UNNEST(array) as element
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY element;
```

To count the occurrence of a specific element, for example 'c', add a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT count(id), UNNEST(array) as element
FROM myTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(array) AS x WHERE x='c')
GROUP BY element;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FILTER` clause to count the occurrences.

Let's say we have a `questions` table with `tags` (array type) and you want to count the questions with `postgresql` tag:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE '{postgresq}' <@ (tags)) as tagCount
FROM posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

More generic function is here;

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_array_elements (
  i_elements pg_catalog.anyarray,
  i_element_to_find pg_catalog.anyelement,
  out count bigint
)
RETURNS bigint AS
$body$
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO count
  FROM unnest(i_elements) u
  WHERE u = i_element_to_find;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

With this way, we can query like this one below;

```
SELECT * FROM count_array_elements(array [ TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE ], TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all contributors here, I learnt a few things.
I am building on work of others in this thread and others in stackoverflow.

I tried to create a function that will count for all the unique elements in the array.

I was targeting returning a json but it seems you can only return as SETOF.

[result of count_element_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZdn6.jpg)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_element_3(str_array text[])
RETURNS setof text
AS
$$
DECLARE
    unique_element_array text[];
    cardinality_array int[];
    retArray text[];
BEGIN
-- Find unique items first
    unique_element_array := array(select distinct unnest(str_array));
    FOR I IN array_lower(unique_element_array, 1)..array_upper(unique_element_array, 1) 
    LOOP
    cardinality_array[I] := (select cardinality(array_positions(str_array, unique_element_array[I])));
    retArray[I] := concat(unique_element_array[I],':',cardinality_array[I]);
    END LOOP;

RETURN QUERY SELECT(retArray::text);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
VOLATILE 
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

with t1 as (SELECT
  sArray,
  c,
  coalesce(array_length( array_positions(sArray, c), 1 ),0) AS count
FROM ( VALUES
  (ARRAY['a','b','c','a','a'], 'a'),
  (ARRAY['a','b','c'], 'd')
) AS t(sArray,c)
)

select sarray, count_element_3(sarray) from t1

    sarray          count_element_3 
    text[]          text
-------------------------------------
    "{a,b,c,a,a}"   "{c:1,a:3,b:1}"
    "{a,b,c}"       "{c:1,a:1,b:1}"
```

Comment: Answer. I thought it will help others who come here after me.

Comment: This should have been shrunk into a comment, not an answer. This doesn't belong here.